# Simulation Click with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, dom-events, simulate

I have a scheduler control, and some divs which can be dragged into the Scheduler which are two separate controls, now I have a problem, I succeeded to make the drag and drop event, when I drop I created an alert to get the coordinates where the drop was made see img below:

[image]

Now what I need to do is simulate a click event so when the user makes a drop an automatic click event is triggered (to trigger the add new event function of the scheduler)... anyone has any idea of how to achieve this?

Comment: Show your code, that will help getting better answers.

Comment: Are you using any kind of JS framework or do you need a plain JS solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Now what I need to do is simulate a click event so when the user makes a drop an automatic click event is triggered (to trigger the add new event function of the scheduler)... anyone has any idea of how to achieve this?

Don't try to simulate the `click`; instead, have both the `click` event and the `drop` event call a central, reusable function. While there are legitimate reasons you might want to simulate a `click` event, normally that's not how you solve this sort of problem.

Answer (score 0):

Define the handler externally. Instead of `... ('click', function(event){})` do `var handler = function(event){}; ... ('click', handler)` and then you can easily do `handler.call(this,event);`.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your replay. Could you provide a sample code? it would really help since I'm not that advanced in javascript. thanks

Comment: No I'm sorry, I'm not that advanced in javascript either.

Answer (score 0):

A Pub/Sub system of any sort would handle this in a more loosely coupled way. For jQuery there is a really tiny but good one at https://gist.github.com/661855

If you're using any other framework you're likely to find others to suit you.